# Can I buy a Windows 11 installation disc or usb with key?

Tags: usb, iso-image, windows-installation, license, windows-11

As in go to a computer store, or online and buy a legal genuine physical copy of Windows 11 as DVD installation media or USB drive, with a key.

Then use this to clean install on a computer and enter the key that came with the purchased copy.

Is this possible?

The closest to this answer is here: [How to download and install Windows 11 right now](https://www.techradar.com/uk/news/how-to-download-windows-11)

But it seems to stop short of saying where to buy a brand new standalone complete (i.e. not an upgrade) legal genuine copy of Windows 11 with key.

Comment: My windows 10 purchase as a system builder was ... just a key, and expected me to download it myself. I suspect 11 will be the same

Comment: Would be nice if people explained why they downvoted. What’s wrong with the question. Thanks to the folks who have contributed with comment and answer so far.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - Microsoft sells boxed USB flash drives that contains Windows 10 in addition to the digital key they sell on the Microsoft Store

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As in go to a computer store, or online and buy a legal genuine physical copy of Windows 11 as DVD installation media or USB drive, with a key.
>
> Then use this to clean install on a computer and enter the key that came with the purchased copy.
>
> Is this possible?

I suspect the retail launch of Windows 11 will happen sometime in 2022.  Microsoft plans on delivering Windows 11 to eligible Windows 10 devices slowly through at least June 2022.

Windows 11 OEM devices should are already being released (i.e Microsoft Surface 8) are slowly being released into the marketplace.

The simplest way to install Windows 11, purchase Windows 10, and install Windows 11 with the key. **Windows 11 essentially is a retail and branded Windows 10 feature update.**

Until they made the announcement, it was expected that some of the changes in Windows 11, were going to be Windows 10 21H2.

> We expect all eligible devices to be offered the free upgrade to Windows 11 by mid-2022. If you have a Windows 10 PC that’s eligible for the upgrade, Windows Update will let you know when it’s available.

Source: [Here](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2021/08/31/windows-11-available-on-october-5/)

Comment: +1 Thank you @ramhound - that sounds plausible. I would be inclined to accept your answer as it covers it. Do you have a source linking back to Microsoft for "Microsoft plans on delivering Windows 11 to eligible Windows 10 devices slowly through at least June 2022." please?

Comment: @therobyouknow - The original Windows 11 announcement blog article.  They are slowly deploying Windows 11 to current Windows 10 devices, an eligible device, might not be pushed Windows 11  until sometime in 2022

Comment: Microsoft hasn’t really made any announcement on a retail strategy for Windows 11. However based on their own statements that the rollout of Windows 11, will go through mid-2022, that tells me the retail release must be in 2022.

Comment: Not to mention W11 is sending older fully functional hardware to the alternative OS world

Comment: +1 indeed @Moab it’s a tension of Landfill burden vs security offered by new hardware. I respect that tension as both sides have genuine merits. Yes repurposing for another OS is a reassuring opportunity. Also, in UK we have Jamies.org.uk - Jamie’s Computer, a non profit doing ethical recycling. No affiliation except that I have donated old tech. No doubt other similar altruistic outfits too.